# Does anyone know, how to copy journey from one BU to another?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to replicate a journey in the new sub BU from a main BU.But its a complicated journey so trying to find out if I Can copy it.

Comment: Have you tried using the deployment manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Deployment Manager to Export your Journey Design from the source BU, and then Deploy to the destination BU.

[Setup Deployment Manager in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_set_up_deployment_manager.htm&type=5)